# How to add text into scrollview of Android app when user clicks button

Tags: c#, button, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an app that collects lyrics into a song that the user selects. I need to make a button that allows them to add the word Verse to the bottom of the list when they click the button. Here is the code that I have so far for it but I am not sure what the proper command would be.

```
        Add Verse 
        Button buttonVerse = FindViewById <Button> (Resource.Id.buttonVerse);
        buttonVerse.Click += delegate {
            addTextPro (false,"Verse");
        };
```

Comment: your question is still unclear to me, can you post some more code!

Comment: `ScrollView` does not have any Text properties, so you will need to add a child which allows for displaying text, such as a `TextView`.